# I have created a script with POST its not working

Tags: php, post

My first code was as follows.
Please tell me whats the problem
**test.php**

```
   <html>
    <title>Speaker</title>
    <body>
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        Number: <input type="text" name="number">
        <input type="submit">

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Welcome.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["number"]))
{$_POST["number"]=$number;}
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{$_POST["name"]= $name;}
if($number<33)
{echo "hello" "$name" "you have been failed" ;
    } 
?>
```

This script is not working. Please tell me where the problem is.

Comment: Your PHP code triggers a parse error. If you cannot see it, please enable error reporting in your development box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting your variables backwards. It should look like:

```
if( isset($_POST["number"]) ){
   $number = (int) $_POST["number"];
}
if( isset($_POST["name"]) ){
   $name = $_POST["name"];
}
if( isset($number) && $number<33 ){
    echo "hello {$name} you have been failed";
}
```

I would also recommend using a more standard `if/else` style like in my example, it is easier to read in larger statements. There was also a bug in your `echo`, you need to concatenate the string with a `.` or put the variable inside double quotes using curly braces. You would want to check for `$number` being set (if it isn't in the `$_POST` then it will generate a warning in your if statement).

Lastly you want to make sure you are converting your inputs to the proper type, and sanitizing them to protect against SQL injections, cross site scripting, and other attacks (this is not shown in my example).

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. It fixed my problem. I am a new learner of programming. I have another problem and question. Where to use "" and where to use ''. i mean where to use double quote and where to use single quote? will you please explain it simply. i have searched many thing but did not understand.

Comment: A string with single quotes will be interpreted literally, but a string with double quotes will evaluate variables. So if `$var = 'test';` then `echo '$var';` will give you "$var" but `echo "$var";` will give you "test". You can use curly braces for cases like `echo "{$var}ing";` to get "testing" since `echo "$varing";` would give you an empty string - it can't tell which part is the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting your variable that's why you aren't able to print. To set any variable you should first declare cariable itself and then give it a value.  so it should be

```
if(isset($_POST["number"])){
    $number = $_POST["number"];
}
if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}
if($number<33) {
    echo "hello".$name." you have been failed" ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither $number or $name are defined
I think you meant to do this :

```
if(isset($_POST["number"]))
{$number=$_POST["number"];}
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{$name=$_POST["name"];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Also, check the `$number` only if `$_POST` is set and is not empty... An the echo was wrong too.

```
<?php
    if( !empty($_POST) )
        $number = $_POST["number"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        if($number<33) {
            echo "hello $name you have been failed" ;
        } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: You would still want to do the assignment like `$number = isset($_POST["number"])? $_POST["number"] : 0;` in case "number" isn't submitted in the request.

Comment: Yes @doublesharp... You're right